# Ways to detect deadlock in a live application

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, deadlock

1. What are the ways to detect deadlocks in a live multi-threaded application?
2. If we found there is a deadlock, are there any ways to resolve it, without taking down/restarting the application?

Answer (score 3):

There are two popular ways to detect deadlocks.

One is to have threads set checkpoints. For example, if you have a thread that has a work loop, you set a timer at the beginning of doing work that's set for longer than you think the work could possibly take. If the timer fires, you assume the thread is deadlocked. When the work is done, you cancel the timer.

Another (sometimes used in combination) is to have things that a thread might block on track what other resources a thread might hold. This can directly detect an attempt to acquire one lock while holding another one when other threads have acquired those locks in the opposite order.

This can even detect deadlock risk without the deadlock actually occurring. If one thread acquires lock A then B and another acquires lock B then A, there is no deadlock unless they overlap. But this method can detect it.

Advanced deadlock detection is typically only used during debugging. Other than coding the application to check each blocking lock for a possible deadlock and knowing what to do if it happens, the only thing you can do after a deadlock is tear the application down. You can't release locks blindly because the resources they protect may be in an inconsistent state.

Sometimes you deliberately write code that you know can deadlock and specifically code it to avoid the problem. For example, if you know lots of threads take lock A and then try to acquire lock B, and some other thread needs to do the reverse, you can code it do a non-blocking attempt to lock B and release lock A if it fails.

Typically, it's more useful to spend your effort making deadlocks impossible rather than making the code detect and work around deadlocks.

Comment: Could java thread dump be used to detect deadlock? It can tell the blocked threads but not sure if deadlock can be detected.

Comment: @AmberBeriwal That can work. With the dump of all thread stacks, you can try to figure out which thread is block trying to get a lock and which thread holds that lock. It's tedious if you have a lot of threads, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a feature called the [`faulthandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html) that's very useful for dealing with deadlocks:

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.register(signal.SIGUSR1)
```

If you're using C++ or any compiler that uses glibc, you can use the backtrace() functions in execinfo.h to print a stacktrace and exit gracefully when you get a signal. You can take a deadlocked program, send it a signal and get a list of all the threads.

In Java, use [`jstack <pid>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr016.html) on the stuck process.