# How to throw exception when deadlock occurs in dining philosophers problem?

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is my dining philosophers problem. When I execute it, sometimes deadlock occurs and the program stops working such as in the following example:

Filozof#0 is taking forks
Filozof#4 is taking forks
Filozof#4 took fork at left
Filozof#3 is taking forks
Filozof#1 is taking forks
Filozof#2 is taking forks
Filozof#3 took fork at left
Filozof#1 took fork at left
Filozof#0 took fork at left
Filozof#2 took fork at left

What I want to do is throwing an exception in the last thread that would have completed the deadlock. I dont want to solve the deadlock problem. What I need is throwing exception. How can I do that?

```
public class Philosopher extends Thread implements Runnable {
            private int forkLeft;
            private int forkRight;
            private int index;

            public Philosopher(int index) {
                forkLeft = index;
                forkRight = (index + 1) % 5;
                this.index = index;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Endless life of a philosopher
                while (true) {
                    takeForks();
                    eat();
                    putDownForks();
                    think();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Take left and right forks
             */
            private void takeForks() {
                System.out.printf("Filozof#%d is taking forks\n", index);
                Table.takeFork(forkLeft);
                System.out.printf("Filozof#%d took fork at left\n", index);
                Table.takeFork(forkRight);
                System.out.printf("Filozof#%d took fork at right\n", index);
            }

            /**
             * Put left and right forks down
             */
            private void putDownForks() {
                System.out.printf("Filozof#%d is putting forks down\n", index);
                Table.putDownFork(forkLeft);
                System.out.printf("Filozof#%d put left fork down\n", index);
                Table.putDownFork(forkRight);
                System.out.printf("Filozof#%d put right fork down\n", index);
            }

            /**
             * Eat for a while
             */
            private void eat() {
                System.out.printf("Filozof#%d is now eating\n", index);
                sleep();
            }

            /**
             * think for a while
             */
            private void think() {
                System.out.printf("Filozof#%d is now thinking\n", index);
                sleep();
            }

            private void sleep() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
    public class Table {
        public static Lock[] forks;
        public static Philosopher[] philosophers;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            philosophers = new Philosopher[5];
            forks = new Lock[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < philosophers.length; i++) {
                philosophers[i] = new Philosopher(i);
                forks[i] = new ReentrantLock();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < philosophers.length; i++) {
                philosophers[i].start();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Locks a fork with given index
         * @param fork index of the fork
         */
        public static void takeFork(int fork) {
            forks[fork].lock();
        }

        /**
         * unlocks a fork with given index
         * @param fork index of the fork
         */
        public static void putDownFork(int fork) {
            forks[fork].unlock();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ways to detect deadlock in a live application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622603/ways-to-detect-deadlock-in-a-live-application)

Comment: Out of curiosity, How do you propose to _handle_ the exception? Do you need an exception to be thrown in each of the five threads? or only in the last thread that would have completed the deadlock?

Comment: @SolomonSlow only in the last thread that would have completed the deadlock

Comment: You're using `Lock` instances... I would search for a `Lock` implementation that does what you want (i.e., has a `lock()` method that throws an exception instead of creating a deadlock.) If the search turned up nothing, then I would write my own. I don't have time to do it for you, but basically, each `Lock` needs to keep a record of what thread has it locked (if any), and what threads are awaiting it (if any), and you need the `lock()` method to search the [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) of lock owners and waiting threads to see whether locking a lock will create a cycle.

Comment: @JohnMontana To be clear: The "dining philosophers problem" exists to *show* what a deadlock is. It is not a coding challenge or something like that. A deadlock is not a problem like a "missing file on disk" that you need to handle. A deadlock is a very bad sign and should be avoided by improving the software design, rather than fixing it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to throw an exception when deadlock occurs, you should just prevent it from occurring. The deadlock is occurring because you aren't releasing the locks in the order that they are taken. In order to avoid this, simply release the locks in the same order that you acquire the locks.

Comment: The whole point of "dining philosophers" is, it's a framework for programming _exercises_ for learning about how deadlocks happen, how to avoid them, how to detect them etc. "Just prevent it from occurring" is the best answer for any kind of production software, but might not be the right answer in this case. (Hard to tell though, because OP has not said _why_ he wants to detect deadlocks.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow the reason why I want to do this in this way is because I am working in a project where I developed an algorithm which compares multi-threading projects which have non deterministic bugs. It compares the failed and successful traces and shows where the bug is.